# Slide RecyclerView up as you swipe it up, or slide recyclerview down as you swipe down

Tags: android, android-recyclerview, sliding

I want to create a `Fragment` with a `RecyclerView` that slides up and shows more items as you slide it up.

Here is an example of what I am talking about.

**Initial Creation:**

[image]

**User Swipes Up to slide `RecyclerView` up, shows more items:**

[image]

There are a few issues, I would like to not use a `CoordinatorLayout`, and I would like to set it to where the items in the `RecyclerView` stack up directly on top of the `EditText`.

This is the layout code I am using:

```
<android.support.design.widget.CoordinatorLayout
android:id="@+id/coordinatorLayout"
xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:visibility="visible">

<android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout
    android:id="@+id/appBarLayout"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="400dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
    android:orientation="vertical">

    <android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout
        android:id="@+id/collapsingToolbar"
        android:layout_width="match_parent"
        android:layout_height="match_parent"
        android:background="@android:color/transparent"
        android:fitsSystemWindows="true"
        app:layout_scrollFlags="scroll|exitUntilCollapsed">

        <View
            android:id="@+id/emptyView"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="400dp"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            app:layout_collapseMode="parallax"/>

    </android.support.design.widget.CollapsingToolbarLayout>

</android.support.design.widget.AppBarLayout>

<android.support.v7.widget.RecyclerView
    android:id="@+id/recyclerView"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    app:layout_behavior="@string/appbar_scrolling_view_behavior"/>

<RelativeLayout
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:orientation="vertical">

        <EditText
            android:id="@+id/editText"
            android:paddingLeft="16dp"
            android:inputType="textAutoCorrect"
            android:layout_centerVertical="true"
            android:background="@android:color/transparent"
            android:layout_width="match_parent"
            android:layout_height="56dp"/>

    </RelativeLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

And I get something like this:

[image]

This is definitely not scalable, and empty view would need to be consistently measured.

Comment: Is there a reason why you don't want a CoordinateLayout implementation?

Answer (score 11, accepted):

I solved this by using a custom `TouchListener` all of the other solutions were very basic and limited to a specific and boxed use-case.

The way I did this was to implement a new `TouchListener` based off of this library:

[BounceTouchListener](https://github.com/surahul/Bounce)

I get the following results:

[image]

Comment: Thanks @AndyRoid for BounceTouchListener

Answer (score 5):

Use `RecyclerView` with 2 types of rows:

1. Empty row/rows colored gray (without divider)
2. Rows with content as you already have

The `RecyclerView` will have to match_parent to the entire fragment

So you will get the right effect of a "blank" area on top of the `RecyclerView`.

[image]

Comment: This would be a solution I would go to off the top of my head, and I did consider this BUT there are a few key issues, you can slide up the entire `RecyclerView` I would like it to not slide past the items. So I basically want to prevent something like image 3

Comment: @AndyRoid I didn't understand what is your issue with that option? Can you explain it with more details?

Comment: In iOS land you can set additional contentInset to the top or bottom of a tableview, this gives additional scrolling area. Is there anything similar in Android? I want to set the live above the edittext and then give additional contentInset below the RecyclerView so that you can scroll just a little bit underneath the keyboard.

Answer (score 0):

You can use [setReverseLayout](https://developer.android.com/reference/android/support/v7/widget/LinearLayoutManager.html#setReverseLayout(boolean)) of LinearLayoutManager

> Used to reverse item traversal and layout order. This behaves similar
>   to the layout change for RTL views. When set to true, first item is
>   laid out at the end of the UI, second item is laid out before it etc.
>   For horizontal layouts, it depends on the layout direction. When set
>   to true, If RecyclerView is LTR, than it will layout from RTL, if
>   RecyclerView} is RTL, it will layout from LTR. If you are looking for
>   the exact same behavior of setStackFromBottom(boolean), use
>   setStackFromEnd(boolean)